# How to catch grails.validation.ValidationException?

Tags: validation, grails

I have simple domain:

```
package app

   class Customers {
   String CUSTOMER
   String NOTE

   static mapping = {
      version false
      id column: 'ID_CUSTOMER', type: 'long',
         generator: 'sequence',
         params: [sequence: 'CUSTOMER_SEQ']
   }

   static constraints = {
      CUSTOMER(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: ['NOTE'])
      NOTE(nullable: true, blank: true) 
   }
}
```

Columns and constraints are created properly in database (I want constraint on customer and note together), but instead of getting:

```
grails.validation.**ValidationException**
```

I am getting:

```
Message: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST2.UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_NOTE) violated
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST2.UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_NOTE) violated
```

Shouldn't I get **ValidationException** when constrains are violated?

Controller code is standard auto code generated by the `generate-all` script.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show any of the controller code - are you checking the return value of `validate()` and `save()` calls (or using `hasErrors()`) and redirecting back so the user can fix the mistakes?

What you're seeing will happen if you change one or both values and they're no longer unique, but you don't call `validate()` or `save()`. That's because at the end of the request, any modified instances will be updated in the database because the session gets flushed, and Hibernate uses its cached copy of the original values to detect modified/dirty instances that haven't been saved and flushed yet.

If you change a value but don't plan on saving the change (e.g. if you set values only for rendering the GSP) be sure to evict the instance from the session by calling `discard()` - Hibernate won't try to push those changes if the instance is no longer attached to the session.

Comment: Strange part is that I have ValidationException when I am trying to save to both columns values that already exist, but SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException when just one already exist.

Comment: there is row (ff,ff) in database and another the same save gives ValidationException

Comment: there is (ff,null) in database and another save gives SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Comment: That might be a bug then - it sounds like some code is using = to compare and in SQL null is never equal to anything, not even null, so there needs to be an isNull check. It's probably an inconsistency that affects multi-column unique but works fine with single-column

Comment: That would be grails or hibernate bug?